# Job offer contingent on continuing education

Tags: hiring-process

Do situations exist where a position is offered but is contingent on the applicant continuing education (Masters or other)? If not contingent, how is the pursuit of an advanced degree usually handled from a new-hire perspective?

Comment: Say you're talking salary and your boss/coworkers know you're working on a degree.  Does this put you in a position to negotiate a raise or new opportunity or (and there may be other outcomes of course) is your department going to chalk you up as a loss. I guess this is very specific to the environment but I've heard that organic growth is nearly extinct in the workplace.

Answer (score 5):

I have seen this in the US, and in fact for some jobs this is a legal requirement.  For example, in some states, public school teachers are required to continue their education with courses towards a masters and beyond.

What is most important is that your employer recognize the impact this requirement has on you.  Will they be reimbursing you for the tuition in some fashion?  Will they be flexible with work schedules when it comes to class time (leaving early) and exams (time to study).  If they are going to require it, then I believe they should support you in these areas, as it is their choice not yours.

Answer (score 2):

I have had an experience with the former (contingent on applicant continuing education).

It was a government program, and my employment hinged on me maintaining a certain GPA and coursework subject (in my case, software engineering). Once I graduated, the program was meant to accelerate my career progress. Unfortunately, the program was cut from the government and I was let go, but still got a free degree out of it (in addition to my salary and benefits, of course).

Now I work at a private company, and they reimburse tuition up to 70%. That means that you only have to pay 30% of the cost of the graduate degree, which is not bad. Companies usually like to see people wanting to attain a higher education, but one thing I would make sure of is to ensure my employer that the coursework will not impact your day-to-day work productivity.

Now of course, we live in the real world, and the chance of part-time coursework affecting your full-time work is a very real possibility. It is usually a better idea to go with employment that is contingent on your studies (like mine) because the employer will be understanding in you working on schoolwork at your day job, where as in the latter example they will not. It is definitely difficult and is not advised if your day job makes you work overtime or if you have a crappy boss.

Answer (score 1):

> Do situations exist where a position is offered but is contingent on
>   the applicant continuing education (Masters or other)?

Yes, there are many jobs which are offered with the expectation that the new hire continues his/her education.

For example, folks can get hired and are required to eventually pass a licensing or certification exam.

As Kelly Tessena Keck and Christopher Estep point out in their comments, teaching, nursing, legal, and other professions take this route.

> Say you're talking salary and your boss/coworkers know you're working
>   on a degree. Does this put you in a position to negotiate a raise or
>   new opportunity or (and there may be other outcomes of course) is your
>   department going to chalk you up as a loss.

This is clearly a discussion you want to have with your boss.

The likely answer is "neither".

In most private-sector US jobs, working on a degree doesn't put you on a guaranteed path to a raise or promotion.

Nor is your department likely to "chalk you up as a loss". Why would they, unless you were planning to go to school full-time and stop working, or unless you indicated that you are leaving once you achieve your degree?

Comment: Teaching and nursing, for example

Comment: It's also very common (if not typical) for lawyers to get hired out of law school and pass the bar.  I've never heard of it in the software industry though (which is mine).